# Cache Simulator in C

Tags: c

Ok this is only my second question, and it's quite a doozy. It's for a school assignment, but no one (including the TAs) seems to be able to help me. It's kind of a tall order but I'm not sure where else to turn.

Essentially the assignment was to make a cache simulator. This version is direct mapping and is actually only a small portion of the whole project, but if I can't even get this down I have no chance with other associativities. I'm posting my whole code because I don't want to make any assumptions about where the problem is.

This is the test case: http://www.mediafire.com/?ty5dnihydnw

And you run the following command:
./sims 512 direct 32 fifo wt pinatrace.out

You're supposed to get:

```
hits: 604037
misses 138349
writes: 239269
reads: 138349
```

But I get:

```
Hits: 587148
Misses: 155222
Writes: 239261
Reads: 155222
```

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for about 12 hours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


struct myCache
{
    int valid;
    char *tag;
    char *block;
};

/*
sim [-h] <cache size> <associativity> <block size> <replace alg> <write policy>
<trace file>
*/

//God willing I come up with a better Hex to Bin convertion that maintains the beginning 0s...
void hex2bin(char input[], char output[])
{
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int x = 4;
    int size;
    size = strlen(input);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] =='0')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='1')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='2')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='3')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='x')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='5')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='6')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='7')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '0';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }    
        else if (input[i] =='8')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='9')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='a')
        {    
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='b')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '0';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='c')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='d')
        {    
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '0';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='e')
        {    
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '0';
        }
        else if (input[i] =='f')
        {
            output[i*x +a] = '1';
            output[i*x +b] = '1';
            output[i*x +c] = '1';
            output[i*x +d] = '1';
        }
    }

    output[32] = '\0';
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    FILE *tracefile;
    char readwrite;
    int trash;
    int cachesize;
    int blocksize;
    int setnumber;
    int blockbytes;
    int setbits;
    int blockbits;
    int tagsize;
    int m;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int xindex;
    int jindex;
    int kindex;
    int lindex;    
    int setadd;
    int totalset;
    int writeMiss = 0;
    int writeHit = 0;
    int cacheMiss = 0;
    int cacheHit = 0;
    int read = 0;
    int write = 0;
    int size;
    int extra;

    char bbits[100];
    char sbits[100];
    char tbits[100];
    char output[100];
    char input[100];
    char origtag[100];


    if (argc != 7)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "-h"))
        {
            printf("./sim2 <cache size> <associativity> <block size> <replace alg> <write policy> <trace file>\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: wrong number of parameters.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    tracefile = fopen(argv[6], "r");

    if(tracefile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File is NULL.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Determining size of sbits, bbits, and tag
    cachesize = atoi(argv[1]);
    blocksize = atoi(argv[3]);
    setnumber = (cachesize/blocksize);
    printf("setnumber: %d\n", setnumber);
    setbits = (round((log(setnumber))/(log(2))));
    printf("sbits: %d\n", setbits);
    blockbits = log(blocksize)/log(2);
    printf("bbits: %d\n", blockbits);
    tagsize = 32 - (blockbits + setbits);
    printf("t: %d\n", tagsize);

    struct myCache newCache[setnumber];

    //Allocating Space for Tag Bits, initiating tag and valid to 0s
    for(i=0;i<setnumber;i++)
    {
        newCache[i].tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tagsize+1));
        for(j=0;j<tagsize;j++)
        {
            newCache[i].tag[j] = '0';
        }
        newCache[i].valid = 0;
    }

    while(fgetc(tracefile)!='#')
    {    
        setadd = 0;
        totalset = 0;
        //read in file
        fseek(tracefile,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        fscanf(tracefile, "%x: %c %s\n", &trash, &readwrite, origtag);

        //shift input Hex
        size = strlen(origtag);
        extra = (10 - size);
        for(i=0; i<extra; i++)
            input[i] = '0';

        for(i=extra, j=0; i<(size-(2-extra)); j++, i++)
            input[i]=origtag[j+2];

        input[8] = '\0';

        // Convert Hex to Binary
        hex2bin(input, output);

        //Resolving the Address into tbits, sbits, bbits
        for (xindex=0, jindex=(32-blockbits); jindex<32; jindex++, xindex++)
    {
            bbits[xindex] = output[jindex];
        }
    bbits[xindex]='\0';

    for (xindex=0, kindex=(32-(blockbits+setbits)); kindex<32-(blockbits); kindex++, xindex++){
        sbits[xindex] = output[kindex];
    }
    sbits[xindex]='\0';

    for (xindex=0, lindex=0; lindex<(32-(blockbits+setbits)); lindex++, xindex++){
        tbits[xindex] = output[lindex];
    }
    tbits[xindex]='\0';

    //Convert set bits from char array into ints
    for(xindex = 0, kindex = (setbits -1); xindex < setbits; xindex ++, kindex--)
        {
            if (sbits[xindex] == '1')
                setadd = 1;
            if (sbits[xindex] == '0')
                setadd = 0;
            setadd = setadd * pow(2, kindex);
            totalset += setadd;
        }

        //Calculating Hits and Misses
        if (newCache[totalset].valid == 0)
        {
            newCache[totalset].valid = 1;
            strcpy(newCache[totalset].tag, tbits);
        }

        else if (newCache[totalset].valid == 1)
        {
            if(strcmp(newCache[totalset].tag, tbits) == 0)
            {
                if (readwrite == 'W')
                {
                    cacheHit++;        
                    write++;
                }
                if (readwrite == 'R')
                    cacheHit++;    
            }
            else
            {
                if (readwrite == 'R')
                {
                    cacheMiss++;
                    read++;
                }
                if (readwrite == 'W')
                {
                    cacheMiss++;
                    read++;
                    write++;
                }
                strcpy(newCache[totalset].tag, tbits);
            }
        }        
    }
    printf("Hits: %d\n", cacheHit);
    printf("Misses: %d\n", cacheMiss);
    printf("Writes: %d\n", write);
    printf("Reads: %d\n", read);
}
```

Comment: PS: I tried so hard to make this readable according to the formatting here. Sorry if it still makes your eyes bleed!

Comment: Shouldn't `else if (input[i] =='x')` in `hex2bin` be `input[i] =='4'`?

Comment: Just because your TA can't figure it out doesn't mean the answer is totally beyond your capabilities. He may know the subject matter better than you, but **you** know your code better than he does, and **you** need to learn to figure out what's wrong on your own.

Comment: @Scott Wales Yes, I have x = 4, conveniently, so it doesn't actually change anything. That's just a "Replace all" error from how many times I've altered that function.

Comment: @Ken Bloom I mean my TAs won't even look at the code. Nothing against them: they have their own projects and finals to work on. I was just mentioning that to show that I have tried to go to people in my class. I've gone through it manually with small tracefiles and it works correctly but I cannot do that with a file that is thousands of lines long and that is where the problem occurs.

Comment: This is, by far, the _best_ homework question that has ever hit SO.

Comment: @Tim Post Haha I'm not sure if I should be pleased with my self or ashamed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two problems.  Firstly, Scott Wales is correct about your `hex2bin()` function - you have a `'x'` where you mean `'4'`.

Secondly, you are not correctly counting a cache miss when you hit an invalid cache slot.  You can simply handle "invalid" with *exactly* the same code path you use for a miss:

```
    if ((newCache[totalset].valid == 1) && (strcmp(newCache[totalset].tag, tbits) == 0))
    {
        /* Hit */
        if (readwrite == 'W')
        {
            cacheHit++;
            write++;
        }
        if (readwrite == 'R')
            cacheHit++;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Miss (cache entry invalid, or wrong tag) */
        if (readwrite == 'R')
        {
            cacheMiss++;
            read++;
        }
        if (readwrite == 'W')
        {
            cacheMiss++;
            read++;
            write++;
        }
        newCache[totalset].valid = 1;
        strcpy(newCache[totalset].tag, tbits);
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I had originally been adding my misses that way but since they were too high to start with I reduced them by removing that code.

I can't believe this was (almost all) because of that stupid 'x'.

/ashamed.